# Expected Value of Coin-Flipping Game

Tags: probability, expected-value

We flip a fair coin until the difference between the number of heads and the number of tails is 2 - what is the expected length of the game? I set up $E_g=E_1+1$ and $E_1=(1/2)(1)+(1/2)(E_g+1)$ to get $E_g=4$ - is this right? ($E_g$ is expected value of the game and $E_1$ is the remaining expected length given one coin is already ahead).

Answer (score 1):

No.  Your equation $E_1=(1/2)(1)+(1/2)E_g$ should have $E_g+1$ because if the leading side loses you are back at the start with one more flip taken. It would be better to have some words justifying the two equations so we can follow your thinking.

After the edit it is correct.

Comment: oop I used $E_g+1$ in my calculation but didn't write it in the equation above - is this logic and answer correct though?